# Kahler differential of finite type algebra over field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ is a finite type algebra over $k$, where $\Omega_{A/k}=0$.

Can we say that $A$ is finite (hence field) over $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "Can we say that $A$ is finite (hence field) over $k$?"

**Answer:** If $\Omega^1_{A/k}=0$ it follows $dim_k(A)=n < \infty$: The result may be proved using a result on commutative algebra found in Hartshorne and a basic property of the module of differentials:

Let $k \rightarrow A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra with $k$ algebraically closed. The following holds for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $A$: $dim(A_{\mathfrak{m}}) \leq dim_k(\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}^2)$. This is may be found in Hartshorne Prop. I.5.2A since $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a Noetherian local ring
with residue field $k$.

Hence if you are able to find a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A$ with $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$, it follows

$$dim(A)=dim(A_{\mathfrak{m}})\leq dim_k(\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}^2)=0.$$

Hence the claim follows from HH.I.5.2A.

**Note:** Since you may assume $k$ to be algebraically closed, it follows any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ satisfies

$$0:=\Omega^1_{A/k}\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{m})\cong \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 $$

hence for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ it follows $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$. The fiber of the "cotangent module/bundle" at a $k$-rational point is the cotangent space.

**Note:** If $dim_k(A)< \infty$ this implies that $A$ is an artinian $k$-algebra. $A$ is not necessarily a field.

It is a well known result in commutative algebra with many different proofs:

[Good argument that $\Omega_{X/k} = 0$ implies that $X$ is finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185027/good-argument-that-omega-x-k-0-implies-that-x-is-finite/4186082#4186082)